# Ruby and CSS code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

I am following a Ruby on Rails tutorial, http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#top and I am stuck at the point where it says how to include the CSS code:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
<!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]-->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>
```

This is what I have in my HTML code. The HTML file is under:

```
/rails_project/sample_app/app/views/layouts$ cat application.html.erb
```

and the CSS code is under:

```
/rails_project/sample_app/public/stylesheets/custom.css
```

but it seems that it doesn't seem to recognize the CSS code and as a result I just get a plain HTML website.

Comment: I added "ruby-on-rails" as a tag.

Comment: and show more of your html code, please. the surrounding context might be relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Rails 3.1, you can use the assets pipeline.

Stick your CSS files in app/assets/stylesheets and they'll be automatically included, compiled iyd they need to be, and minified provided you use code similar to the following in your layout:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Does it work if you use a regular css tag like

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/stylesheets/your_css.css">
```